# Sending and receiving multiple JSON literals PHP Socket

Tags: php, sockets

I'm currently encountering problem with receiving a data the problems are as follows

Server:

```
        foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {
        $receiveData = "";
        $byte = @socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 0xFFFF, 0);
        while ($byte >= 1) {
            $receiveData .= $buf . PHP_EOL;
            break;
        }
```

Client:

```
public function send($data)
{
    if (is_array($data)) $data = json_encode($data);
    @socket_write($this->socket_master, $data, strlen($data));
}
```

I am trying to send **JSON** data

```
$this->send(["clientName" => "Jean"]);
$this->send(["verification" => true]);
```

The problem is on the socket server the json_decode is unable to parse the data because of the following situation:

**Output**:

```
{"clientName":"jean"}{"verification":true}
```

**Expected Output**:

```
{"clientName":"jean"}
{"verification":true}
```

Thank you for having had the time to read and I hope the problem will be solved !

regards, Nicolas

Comment: maybe theres issue with `PHP_EOL` which value is based on the system where php running, try chaning it to the `"\n"`, or the `socket_recv` reveives all the data which waiting to be read, not each `socket_write` separately, this: `@socket_write($this->socket_master, $data."\n", strlen($data)+1);` could help

Comment: It's work but the only problem is I want to separate the data like `string(47) "{"clientName":"Jean"}"
string(54) "{"verification":true}"` and not `string(47) "{"clientName":"Jean"}
{"verification":true}`
" @Kazz

Comment: I made something like explode("\n", $receiveData); to get each data do you think it's a good practice because it's work ? @Kazz

Comment: its good as long as you dont send "\n" in your data, `$this->send(["clientName" => "foo\nbar"]);` breaks it for example

Comment: actually it wont breaks becuase json_encode keeps it as '\n'

Comment: but `$this->send("foo\nbar");` does break it, you can sanitize your separator in data before sending them and unsanitize after receiving

Comment: Ok solved I made something like that `array_filter(explode("\n", $buffer), function ($content) { return !empty($content);});` to get my data I use array_filter to remove the empty array useless so Thanks for your help! @Kazz

Comment: I made sanitize by using str_replace before sending and unsanitize after for string value @Kazz